# What libraries can you use for ViewModel binding with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to use a library to automatically bind Views and Models in Backbone.js.  When an input element is modified, I want it to modify the corresponding property in the view, etc.  What library do you favor for doing this?

Comment: Backbone should be able to do that without extra libraries. Search on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=listen+changes+backbone+javascript

Comment: But it doesn't do it automatically.  I asked about automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `ModelBinder` is for. I use it regularly and am very happy with the project. You can find it [here](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder).